# How to reload page once I push query params in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, router

```
filter() {
      this.$router.push({
        query: {
          bathrooms: this.selectedBathroom,
          beds: this.selectedBed,
          minPrice: this.selectedMinPrice,
          maxPrice: this.selectedMaxPrice,
          minLandSize: this.selectedMinLandSize,
          maxLandSize: this.selectedMaxLandSize,
          minLotSize: this.selectedMinLotSize,
          maxLotSize: this.selectedMaxLotSize,
          minYear: this.selectedMinYear,
          maxYear: this.selectedMaxYear,
        },
      })
    }
```

Once the filter method is called, the query params is pushed to the link, but the page doesn't reload. How do I make the page to reload once the query params is pushed?

Comment: If the query params is the source of truth, then your view should update automatically, otherwise you need to instruct your view to update (however you have that coded). Worst case you can hard-reload the page with `location.reload()`.

Comment: much better way: https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/